# Core Data save crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, concurrency

I have a `UITableView` that fetches data from `CoreData` using `FetchedResultsController` and it registers for the data update.

On a second thread, I download the data from the server and update the same data (that's used by the `UITableView`). The update is not complicated and It is just updating a BOOL field of the entity.

When I call the save on Object Context, I get this exception: `NSInternalInconsistencyException` and the reason is

```
"Failed to process pending changes before save.  The context is still dirty after 100 attempts. ..."
```

If I do not save right after the update but only at the time when the application is about to terminate, the application runs fine and the `UITableView` is correctly updated and the data is persisted.

Any pointer on why that might be happening? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed object contexts are not thread safe. Do you have a separate `MOC` for each thread?

If so, I believe the correct pattern is to register for `NSManagedObjectDidSaveNotifications` from the background `MOC` such that you can do a `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` on the main `MOC` (from the main thread).  This will keep your `MOCs` in sync; it does not happen automatically.

Comment: Oh...I'm keeping a singleton MOC from a sort-of-like CoreDataUtil class. Now feeling stupid. @_@

One question: changes saved from one MOC will be reflected in another MOC? Thanks!!!