# Using Core Data using multithreading and notifications

Tags: multithreading, core-data, notifications

Here's yet another question on Core Data and multithreading:

I'm writing an application on the iPhone that retrieves XML data from the internet, parses it in a background thread (using NSXMLparser) and saves the data in Core Data using its own NSManagedObjectContext. I have a class - let's call it DataRetriever - that does this for me.

There are different UIViewControllers that then retrieve the data to display it in their respective UITableViews, of course this happens on the main thread using  NSFetchedResultsControllers and a single managed object context that is used for reading.

I've read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090039/core-data-save-crashes), which tells me that I need to register for NSManagedObjectDidSaveNotifications on the background thread (this will be done by the DataRetriever class I suppose) and then call the mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification method on the reading context from that class on the main thread. This, I think, is totally thread-unsafe. I might have interpreted this the wrong way, though.

I've also read [this part](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1) of Apple's documentation on the subject (*Track Changes in Other Threads Using Notifications)*, and it tells me to simply register for NSManagedObjectDidSaveNotifications *coming from* the reading context *in* the view controller *on* the main thread and then it would have to call mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification to update its reading context.

I went with Apple's recommendations: I now have my view controllers register themselves to NSManagedObjectDidSaveNotifications on the main thread using the reading managed object context as the source of the notifications. Doing this on the writing context probably isn't thread safe, and Apple's documentation isn't very specific on this.

Result: No crashes, but I am not receiving any notifications either.

Side note: I've read in Apple's documentation that notifications don't automatically propagate to other threads and I might even be listening for notifications from the wrong context, but why is Apple telling me to do it this way, then?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

-- EDIT --

Just to be clear, I'm registering for notifications coming from a *particular* NSManagedObjectContext, Apple's documentation specifically states ([here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html)) that some system frameworks may use an instance of Core Data themselves, so I could be receiving notifications from contexts that don't concern me if I don't specify a source. The documentation I referred to earlier on doesn't say anything about this, though. Any comments on this design choice are welcome.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

Answer (score 1):

The UI runs on the main thread so you want any intensive processing that might bog the UI down done on another thread. You have the context in the main thread listen for notifications because the main thread context is usually the only one that needs to update itself because of changes by other context in other threads.

All this is thread safe because data won't be deleted from the persistent store as long as one or more context is still using it. So, if context A has an object with the data while context B deletes another object representing the same data, the object in context A remains alive until context A calls for a merge.

Basically, each context operates in its own little world until you call merge. The race conditions that normally bedevil thread based data operations don't occur with Core Data.

Comment: So, basically what you're saying is, the way I'm doing it now is the right one? Because it's not working. I also tried registering my view controllers (in their respective -ViewDidLoad methods) to notifications coming from the writing context. But on the main thread. This crashes my app at random points (no real surprise there I suppose, but I'm at a loss what to do). I could try doing the registering on the background thread, is that an option? Please be clear on what I'm doing wrong and what I'm doing right.

Comment: It sounds like your doing things correctly. After all, most people use the pattern recommended by Apple. I can't tell you want is causing the crash without more detail. You might want to post a new question detailing exactly where the crash occurs.